# Does anyone know how to install a program called Flacon on elementary OS?

Tags: release-juno, audio, thirdpartyapps

I have just moved from Ubuntu 18 to elementary OS OK. Wow, I definitely won't look back!

I was using **Flacon** (an audio .cue file splitter) on Ubuntu, but can't seem to be able to install it in elementary OS. Anyone has an idea? Or another similar program? 
Thanks!

Fred

Comment: I've deleted your accepted answer because it was a duplicate of your own answer. Please feel free to accept your own answer, instead.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks, the 'sudo add-apt-repository' command on its own was not working. 
I found the answer:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:flacon
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install flacon
```

Solved!

Answer (score 2):

If it runs in Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic) 99% will run on elementary OS Juno [release-juno](/questions/tagged/release-juno)

From their website, run to install it:

- `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:flacon`

  - When you add a PPA, `add-apt-repository` runs `apt update` after so you won't need to do it. If it does not, just run manually `sudo apt update` and then install
- `sudo apt install flacon`

ref: https://flacon.github.io/download/